# Get the name of a property by the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

I'd rather be using Enums but I need an easy way to display strings.

```
 public struct OpportunityStatus
    {
        public static string Active { get; } = "stat_WWuMrC5QlVlr7geYuxDStp5BfrEtfl63H8JaQoIdYAG";
        public static string Lost { get; } = "stat_LOjFr8l9IG0XQ0Wq23d0uiXe3fDEapCW7vsGECZnKy4";
    }
```

This works fine if I need to get the status code of a lost opportunity in my code without typing the status code. It helps with the readability, same as an emum.

How do I do it in reverse though? How can I get the property name by the string value:

```
    public static object FindByStatusCode(string statusCode)
    {
        return typeof(LeadStatus)
           .GetProperty("stat_WWuMrC5QlVlr7geYuxDStp5BfrEtfl63H8JaQoIdYAG");
    }
```

Should return "Active"

Comment: You'll have to implement some kind of mapping scheme from the string values to the property.

Comment: I think your logic is somehow broken. Instead of two properties, why not use a `Dictionary`? Why do you even care for the proprty-name? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: It really would help if you [explained why you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @HimBromBeere because there are dozens of properties, not two. I wanted the code readability and the same ease of use as using an Enum.

Comment: what are you doing with the property afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using reflection, but be aware that it can be very slow...

```
    public static string GetPropertyByValue(Type staticClass, string value)
    {
        var typeInfo = staticClass.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                .Where(p => string.Compare(p.GetValue(null) as string, value) == 0)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
        return typeInfo?.Name;
    }
```

This will return the name of a static property with a certain value. It requires that the property be static.

You can call it like this:

```
var name = GetPropertyByValue(typeof(OpportunityStatus), "stat_WWuMrC5QlVlr7geYuxDStp5BfrEtfl63H8JaQoIdYAG");
```

Where `name` will equal `Active`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement a 'smart' enum. Check out ardalis on git hub. [enter link description here](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum)

You can also find this code as a NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some mapping from a string-value to a property. Thus you should also use a data-structure that supports mapping keys to values. Best option thus is a `Dictionary`:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    { "Active", "stat_WWuMrC5QlVlr7geYuxDStp5BfrEtfl63H8JaQoIdYAG" }, 
    { "Lost", "stat_LOjFr8l9IG0XQ0Wq23d0uiXe3fDEapCW7vsGECZnKy4" }
};
```

Now you can get the key that maps to a given value:

```
var name = map.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "stat_WWuMrC5QlVlr7geYuxDStp5BfrEtfl63H8JaQoIdYAG");
```

Depending on if you need to get keys by values more often you may also exchange key and value, making `"Active"` the actual *value* in the dictionary, instead of the *key*.